# Shell/Bash Script to reverse the text in every other column?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm currently trying to write a bash/shell script that pulls data from a .csv and reverses all the string values in every other column and outputs to a new csv. I have a script that grabs every other column but I'm not sure how to reverse the strings in those columns.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {s=$NF; 
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) 
   printf ("%s%c", $i, i + 2 <= NF ? "," : "\n") 
}' input.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: What does the input data look like?

Comment: with `rev` you can reverse strings. For example `echo "value" | rev` would produce `eulav`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ seq 100 141 | pr -6ats, | 
  awk -F, 'function rev(x) {r=""; 
                            for(j=length(x);j;j--) r=r substr(x,j,1); 
                            return r}
           BEGIN {OFS=FS} 
                 {for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2) $i=rev($i)}1' 

001,101,201,103,401,105
601,107,801,109,011,111
211,113,411,115,611,117
811,119,021,121,221,123
421,125,621,127,821,129
031,131,231,133,431,135
631,137,831,139,041,141
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
abc,def,ghi,klm

$ rev file
mlk,ihg,fed,cba

$ rev file |
  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{split($0,a); next} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) $i=a[NF-i+1]} 1' - file
cba,def,ihg,klm
```

Comment: or perhaps with `paste d, file <(rev file) | awk ... ` might be simpler